# Almamofire + Swift + Access Web Service with custom parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hello I am trying to implement ALAMOFIRE to consume a Web Service.
When I use this via query string have success in the operation,

CODE:

```
let url = "http://204.16.1.36/teste.asmx/MyImage?value=ok" 
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
   debugPrint(response)
}
```

LOG:

```
[Request]: http://204.16.1.36/teste.asmx/MyImage?value=ok
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6080000313c0> { URL: http://204.16.1.36/teste.asmx/MyImage?value=ok } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 40;
    Date = "Tue, 04 Oct 2016 15:21:30 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=9";
} }
[Data]: 40 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    app =     {
        node =         {
            result = ok;
        };
    };
}
```

[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 497287293.718, "Initial Response Time": 497287297.096, "Request Completed Time": 497287297.098, "Serialization Completed Time": 497287297.099, "Latency": 3.378 secs, "Request Duration": 3.380 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 3.380 secs }

It turns out that this case can not consume the service via querystring. I searched the Web but did not find an example that works as you like. so I decided to ask your help.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you so much

PS. The Web service works. I am using the following code to access it via QueryString

Comment: Did you solve this?